# How can I adjust my bootstrap based css code so it is more responsive to the page width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nexo75j/) as you can see there I have a webpage with two texts, one below another. It works great on wide screens, but when I shrink the webpage - or run the webpage on mobile - it is messed up, like on this screenshot:

[image]

I thought about doing it more responsive by adding CSS mobile queries, but then in the code I have:

```
@media (max-width: 545px) {


.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:330px;
  top:0;
  position:relative;
}

.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:320px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:330px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}
}

@media (max-width: 435px) {

.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:380px;
  top:0;
  position:relative;
}

.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:370px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:380px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}

}

@media (max-width: 378px) {

 .outer{
  width:100%;
  height:460px;
  top:0;
  position:relative;
}

.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:460px;
  margin-bottom:0px;

}

}
```

etc., so lot's of values for different screen widths. I suspect there's some other way of doing that, the most responsive way in which I don't need to cover each screen width separately in mobile CSS...
Can you give me any hint how could I change my code so it works independently on any device/screen width?
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you are using bootstrap, have you considered using the 'collapse' feature (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)? It's very easy to set up and accomplishes nearly the same thing with way less markup/css, and it works well on mobile too.  The only thing is transition is not quite the same, although there may be a way to modify it.  I added a collapse example to the bottom of your jsfidde: https://jsfiddle.net/2nexo75j/19/

Answer (score 5):

Set minimum width and height for each class so that the page stops adjusting the text with screen resolutions that are too small. Add min-height:123px; and min width:456px; (adjust px as needed) so that they do not overlap on small screens.

Note: This isn't very good for mobile.

Comment: thanks for this comment. Can you tell me why this is not very good for mobile?

Comment: With this method, your content does not alter for different screen resolutions. So if your mobile device is smaller than the minimum height or width, then the user needs to slide their screen over to see all the content rather than all of it fitting into the screen

Comment: ok, I get it, so hmm... Is there any better way that I could use here? I tried some of the native bootstrap classes, but with no success 

Comment: You could try putting a box around the text with a % height and width so that it shrinks as the screen resolution adjusts. This way the boxes will avoid each other.

Answer (score 4):

In your fiddle you are setting the height of each div (inner1 and inner2), and when you compress the page width to about 150px (you picture) the divs are overflowing. Setting the height of an elements is not done often, at least from my experience. On mobile platforms width is usually more of a concern.

Setting the overflow attribute inside your css for each div fixed the issue for me.

```css
.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:270px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
overflow: auto;
}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:280px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is a reference for the overflow property. Using auto at least allows for scrolling and wont cut off the text.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Bootstrap actually has a grid system made for the exact purpose of making the width values responsive to screen size.
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Also, setting the viewport width for mobile phones will load the css to run at the actual screen width of the phone, rather than the pixel density width of the screen: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks! I added `overflow: auto` and the scrollbars appeared. However - is there any other way of doing that? You suggested using bootstrap grid system, could you show me some example of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you run into is caused by the content of .inner1 becoming too high and showing up in your .inner2. The .inner1 is able to become too high because of their overflow. It shows your text even past the height you specified. To stop this behavior apply

```
.inner1{
overflow:hidden;  
}
```

That said, I cannot recommend using the method you have been using to make the content appear/disappear (with a fixed height). I would personally use display:none and remove display:none by code (and possible animation) in this scenario. But that is beyond the question asked, so I won't go into that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nexo75j/1/)

**HTML (with bootstrap)**

```
<div class= "container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-7 company">
                        <h2>this is my title</h2>
                        <div class="companyDescription" >
                            <div class="outer">
                                <div class="inner1" id="inner1">
                                <h5>"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet
                                    </h5><h5>Some kind of subtitle</h5>
                                    <h5><a id="readMore" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">read more...</a></h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner2">
                                    <h5><a id="readLess" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">...read less</a></h5>
                                    <h5>As the use of typewriters grew in the late 19th century, the phrase began appearing in typing and stenography lesson books as a practice sentence. Early examples of publications which used the phrase include Illustrative Shorthand by Linda Bronson (1888), How to Become Expert in Typewriting: A Complete Instructor Designed Especially for the Remington Typewriter (1890)
                                    </h5>
                                    <h5>the last subtitle.</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .company {
  padding-top: 160px;
  color: #000;
}

.companyDescription {
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:280px;
  top:0;
  position:relative;
}

.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:270px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  overflow:hidden;/*ONLY ONE NEW CSS LINE!*/
}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:280px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

**Javascript (with jQuery)**

```
$('#readMore').click(function(){
    $('.companyDescription').animate({
        scrollTop:$('#inner1').outerHeight()+30
    }, 1000);
})
$('#readLess').click(function(){
    $('.companyDescription').animate({
        scrollTop:0
    }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Hm, ok, thank you for that clarification... I just tested it without mobile queries and it almost works in my case, there's still some problem with scrolling the text automatically though... Could you show me the way of how to implement the solution you suggested (with adding and removing `display:none` instead of using my way (with scrolling)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code you can also go through below link -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nexo75j/14/)

HTML Code -

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 company">
      <h2>this is my title</h2>
      <div class="companyDescription">
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner1" id="inner1">
            <h5>"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet
                                        </h5>
            <h5>Some kind of subtitle</h5>
            <h5><a id="readMore" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">read more...</a></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="inner2">
            <h5 style="display:none;"><a id="readLess" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">...read less</a></h5>
            <h5 style="display:none;">As the use of typewriters grew in the late 19th century, the phrase began appearing in typing and stenography lesson books as a practice sentence. Early examples of publications which used the phrase include Illustrative Shorthand by Linda Bronson (1888), How to Become Expert in Typewriting: A Complete Instructor Designed Especially for the Remington Typewriter (1890)
                                        </h5>
            <h5 style="display:none;">the last subtitle.</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$('#readMore').click(function() {
    $('#readMore').css('display','none');
  $('.inner2').find('h5').css('display','block');
})
$('#readLess').click(function() {
$('#readMore').css('display','block');
  $('.inner2').find('h5').css('display','none');
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work as I wanted to, sorry :( It shows me the first paragraph and a link, when I click it the first paragraph does not disappear (Scroll up), and the 2nd paragraph appears...

Comment: so you want that if you click on link it scroll and goes to the next paragraph and if you click on the other link it revert back to its first paragraph with scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap already provide the best responsive design. But still if you want to add more responsiveness you can add your own classes with the html tags and then use media queries for specific width.

```
<div class="container class1">
    content here
</div>

<ul class="list-item class2">
  <li> list item </li>
</ul>
```

now you have to apply your css on your given classes which in this case are `class1` and `class2`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We got 2 choices,

**1. Set a large static height...**

Change the statically set width to a large number like say `250px` which will work well for low res... but will have too much of (ugly) white space on desktop.

```
.inner1{
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner2{
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**2. Calculate height dynamically on `resize`...**

This work work for all resolutions with just as much whitespace as desired on all resolutions ;)
For this

First wrap the contents in `.inner1` and `.inner2` in a container, we used `article` here... this will help us determine the height of content.

Now Set height to 100% for `.inner1` and `.inner2`...

```
.inner1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set height as 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.inner2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set height as 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Then give `.outer` a default height, like maybe `160px`

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Finally some JS to make it work ;)

**Update**
We use a function assigned to a var instead of using an anonymous function.

On resizing window, we check the heights of content in inner1 and inner2, use the one with more content using `Math.max` then add 25px gutter to it and set it as `.outer` height...

```
  var fixWidths = function() {
    var
      $cDesc = $('.companyDescription');
    $cDesc.find('.outer').css(
      'height',
      Math.max(
        $cDesc.find('.inner1').children('article').outerHeight(),
        $cDesc.find('.inner2').children('article').outerHeight()
      ) + 25 // Maximum of the two
    )
  }

  $(window).resize(fixWidths);
  fixWidths();
```

**Update**
Make sure your JS code is wrapped in...

```
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

This will wait until doc is loaded...

At the end we trigger resize programmatically, to set the correct initial state.

### A working example

```js
$(function() {
  $('#readMore').click(function() {
    $('.companyDescription').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#inner1').outerHeight() + 30
    }, 1000);
  })
  $('#readLess').click(function() {
    $('.companyDescription').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
  })

  var fixWidths = function() {
    var
      $cDesc = $('.companyDescription');
    $cDesc.find('.outer').css(
      'height',
      Math.max(
        $cDesc.find('.inner1').children('article').outerHeight(),
        $cDesc.find('.inner2').children('article').outerHeight()
      ) + 25 // Maximum of the two
    )
  }

  $(window).resize(fixWidths);
  fixWidths();
});
```

```css
.company {
  padding-top: 160px;
  color: #000;
}
.companyDescription {
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.inner1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Set height as 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.inner2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Set height as 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 company">
      <h2>this is my title</h2>
      <div class="companyDescription">
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="inner1" id="inner1">
            <article>
              <h5>"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet
                                        </h5>
              <h5>Some kind of subtitle</h5>
              <h5><a id="readMore" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">read more...</a></h5>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div class="inner2">
            <article>
              <h5><a id="readLess" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">...read less</a></h5>
              <h5>As the use of typewriters grew in the late 19th century, the phrase began appearing in typing and stenography lesson books as a practice sentence. Early examples of publications which used the phrase include Illustrative Shorthand by Linda Bronson (1888), How to Become Expert in Typewriting: A Complete Instructor Designed Especially for the Remington Typewriter (1890)
                                        </h5>
              <h5>the last subtitle.</h5>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the **updated** fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/2nexo75j/16/

Comment: On desktop it reaches `142px`, where as on mobile it gets as large as `430px`, so no unnecessary, ugly whitespace. ;-)

Comment: Hm, I tested your solution and I'm getting a strange bug in my code... when I refresh the page I see the outer div not resized properly, but it expands when I resize the browser in any way... Is there a way of setting it up on the page load?

Comment: Yeah... calling `resize` programmatically should have done the trick... but we can have it in a different function and call that function after binding it to `resize`...

Comment: Thank, I'm gonna accept your answer. My problem - that bug - still exists though and is related to the fact I have those divs on a second carousel slide, I wrote about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305262/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-the-div-placed-in-the-2nd-slide-of-bootstrap-carouse the problem is when loading the 2nd slide the divs are not yet visible, so their height is equal to 0. Is there anything that comes to your mind that could help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I think you should do a new question with effect reproduced in a `snippet` or `jsfiddle` with the name of carousel you are using, it entirely depends on the feature's of carousel you are using...

Comment: Most carousels support custom events which can be harnessed to do such stuff ;-)

Comment: Be sure to post the link to question here so I can check it out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you included "jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" file? and is order of all css js files are correct?
Because same code of yours with the same styling and scripting working for me.Try this bellow code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#readMore').click(function () {
                $('.companyDescription').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#inner1').outerHeight() + 30
                }, 1000);
            });
            $('#readLess').click(function () {
                $('.companyDescription').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .company {
            padding-top: 160px;
            color: #000;
        }

        .companyDescription {
            margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .outer{
            width:100%;
            height:280px;
            top:0;
            position:relative;
        }

        .inner1{
            width:100%;
            height:270px;
            margin-bottom:0px;

        }
        .inner2{
            width:100%;
            height:280px;
            margin-bottom:0px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7 company">
                <h2>this is my title</h2>
                <div class="companyDescription" >
                    <div class="outer">
                        <div class="inner1" id="inner1">
                            <h5>"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the English alphabet
                            </h5><h5>Some kind of subtitle</h5>
                            <h5><a id="readMore" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">read more...</a></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inner2">
                            <h5><a id="readLess" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">...read less</a></h5>
                            <h5>As the use of typewriters grew in the late 19th century, the phrase began appearing in typing and stenography lesson books as a practice sentence. Early examples of publications which used the phrase include Illustrative Shorthand by Linda Bronson (1888), How to Become Expert in Typewriting: A Complete Instructor Designed Especially for the Remington Typewriter (1890)
                            </h5>
                            <h5>the last subtitle.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use clearfix class

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```